# TinyMCE link url not having the protocol

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have added [Link plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/link/) to TinyMCE. 
However, when I use a URL from the same site the TinyMCE is displayed, it does not retain the URL as it is in the URL field in the 'Insert/Edit link' dialog box (This happens when I click 'Save').

How can I retain the full address (*including the protocol as I have typed*) in the URL field?

Note: I need to retain this URL as it is with the protocol as I sanitize the URLs which have no protocol mentioned. Thus, I really need to have the URL exactly as I type in the URL field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of configuration options that tell TinyMCE how to deal with URLs.  The documentation for these settings can be found here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

In particular I believe you want these two settings:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false
```

I have created a TinyMCE Fiddle to show these in action:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xVgaab/1

If you comment out the two settings referenced above you will see the behavior of the link `href` changes.